# Use AsyncTask or Service to download video from server

Tags: android, download

I want to download a video (mpeg) from my server and need to save it on the SD card. Is it bettet to use an `AsyncTask` or a `Service`?

Could you give me a concept of when to use which?

Comment: Ya, You should use AsyncTask to include downloding process of your video in doInBackground() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) If you just have to download it and save it to sd card and no other thing to do with it or if it is a very large video file use and doesn't require frequent interaction with UI thread Intent Service

(2) If it is a very small video file, use async task.

(3) else if it is not too large use normal service

Comment: So according to performance wise what is the best way to download a video and save in card?

Comment: I think you should first see how big is your file and what you actually have to do with that file. If there is no interaction with the UI thread at all than you should go for intent service.

Answer (score 2):

Android provides a `DownloadManager` class which will handle background downloads with minimal effort.

```
dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
final DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(uri))
        .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getContext(), "downloads", "myVideo.avi");
int downloadId = dm.enqueue(request);
```

By persisting `downloadId` it lets you cancel the download and it will also notify you upon completion with a broadcast. If needed, you can even query for progress.

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on your need.

if your download needs to update any UI/UX content after successful downloading then please go ahead to use AsyncTask.

If that is not your case then please use the Service class by launching a separate Thread process inside it or you can also use IntentService.

Comment: Can you give me any link of any tutorial based on that

Comment: Is there any library for that?

Comment: Tutorial link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your need like

**Async**
  1. task is used to run when button is clicked.
  2. Async task used for one time use.

**Services**
  1. You may use Service if you want to download continuously from server like download images whenever new came in server. 
  
2. Services executes in background continuously.

It is faster to use Async task if you have to done task once per click or other on events.